# Trying to Add SameSite=None header with fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, fetch

Currently I am using the Unsplash API (third-party) to get a random photo for a chrome extension I am building. Using fetch, I am able to hit an endpoint and get the photo but I keep getting this warning in the chrome console:

`A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://unsplash.com/ was set without the SameSite attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with SameSite=None and Secure. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.`

Here is my code

`background.js`

```
// Request for image resource
fetch(url, {
    mode: "cors",
    // credentials: "include", I used include before and it gave me errors
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })
// received image resource and now need to jsonify the response
    .then(function(result) {
      return result.json();
    })
// Grab key value from json
    .then(function(photo) {
      let photoImage = photo.urls.full;
// set storage
      chrome.storage.sync.set({ background: photoImage }, function(result) {});
    })
```

I understand that this is a cors request so I must somehow set my request to "SameSite=None" and "Secure".

Comment: https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained

Comment: I believe this needs to be set on the *other* server, i.e. the cross site one

Comment: If, for whatever reason you want to fix the server cookie, you'll have to use `chrome.cookies` API. Another possibility is to override the `Set-Cookie` header directly inside `chrome.webRequest` API listener like onHeadersReceived.